# Zsh says "no matches found" when trying to download video with youtube-dl

Tags: linux, zsh

I downloaded youtube-dl using pip on CrunchBang (a Debian Wheezy distro). When I run

```
youtube-dl {video URL}
```

I get

```
zsh: no matches found: {video URL}
```

I guess it has something to do with zsh, because I found some users on Arch forums complaining about it. When I switched to bash it worked.

Comment: @Ramhound well switching to bash is not a big deal, but why switching to bash every time you want to download a video? besides i was working in virualenv switched to bash to try it and now my virtualenvwrapper is messed up, i need to uninstall it for it to work again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507186/python-virtualenv-no-module-named-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader

Comment: this command solved my issue:
setopt +o nomatch Ref => https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310540/how-to-get-rid-of-no-match-found-when-running-rm

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Try quoting the URL, e.g.

```
youtube-dl '{video URL}'
```

in your notation, to avoid possible interpretation of special characters in the string.

Comment: why no one mention that? it works, i will accept it in 6 minutes, the system doesn't let me accept it right away

Comment: @Fischer By the way: my Zsh (on OS X in iTerm2 with oh-my-zsh) automatically escapes shell-specific characters like `&` and `!`, so there might be an option to configure that.

Comment: @slhck i just tried it on xterm doesn't work, i don't have xterm2, i'm using oh-my-zsh too.. yes i guess i have to configure my zsh for that, i guess bash does it by default because i haven't configured it, still using the default configuration

Comment: @Fischer: You'll need to load the `url-quote-magic` funtion to get special shellcharacters to be quotes automatically in URLs: `autoload -Uz url-quote-magic; zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic`

Comment: Quotes. I feel like an idiot..

Answer (score 18):

This was already mentioned in the comments, but it deserves its own answer:

```
autoload -Uz bracketed-paste-magic
zle -N bracketed-paste bracketed-paste-magic

autoload -Uz url-quote-magic
zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
```

This causes pasted URLs to be automatically quoted, without needing to disable globbing.

Place the above snippet in your `~/.zshrc` file to persist this setting for future terminal sessions.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable globbing for all commands with:

```
unsetopt nomatch
```

You can put it in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `setopt nomatch`?

Comment: @TomHale no, because `nomatch` is the setting that causes errors on unmatched patterns. Disabling it can also be done with `no_nomatch`.