# How can I disable globbing for URL arguments in Zsh?

Tags: zsh

I just wanted to download a YouTube video using `youtube-dl`, however, `zsh` interprets the questionmark `?` (which separates the query part of the URL) as a globbing wildcard operator (which matches any single character) and thus it aborts the command with the following error message:

```
$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDSESarTQXk
zsh: no matches found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDSESarTQXk
```

Is there a way to make `zsh` recognize URLs, perhaps using regular expression, so that it doesn’t try to glob them?

Comment: @JakeGould: I don't remember having to do that when I used `oh-my-zsh`, however, I can’t find the particular setting and was hoping that someone knew it off the top of their head. Perhaps they've just disabled the `?` globbing wildcard operator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could disable the `NOMATCH`" option of *zsh*:

```
setopt NO_NOMATCH
```

While the `NOMATCH` option is enabled (which is the default) *zsh* prints an error message if a pattern does not match a filename. By disabling `NOMATCH`, patterns that do not match a filename are kept unchanged in the argument list.

Note that the name of the option is really `NOMATCH`, so you have to use `NO_NOMATCH` to disable it, setting `MATCH` does not work.

**Attention**: This affects all globbing, not just URLs. So if you rely in any way on *zsh* returning errors when patterns do not match, this is not the way to go. (Sadly, unlike with `NULL_GLOB` there is no glob qualifier that allows enabling/disabling `NOMATCH` per case.)

Comment: +1 for explaining the consequences of `NOMATCH`, although I think your answer should have been posted to the duplicate question. And one remark: You can at least disable the `NOMATCH` behavior temporary with the `noglob` command, e.g. `noglob youtube-dl url?foo=bar`

Comment: A *much* better solution is to automatically quote URLs: https://superuser.com/a/1237124/93988

Comment: This worked for me.  For some reason, putting quotes around the URL does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the URL in quotes, and it works.

```
$ youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDSESarTQXk'
[youtube] eDSESarTQXk: Downloading webpage
[youtube] eDSESarTQXk: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] eDSESarTQXk: Extracting video information
...
```

Comment: One can also simply automatically quote pasted URLs: https://superuser.com/a/1237124/93988